# Frequency of signal

Tags: signal, frequency

I have a signal like \$\sin(2t)\$.

The frequency of this signal is \$f=\frac{1}{\pi}\$, but I am confused here because this \$\pi\$ equals 3.14 or 180 degrees if the signal is \$\sin(2\pi t)\$, then \$f=1\$ and everything is clear.

Please tell me what is the difference between them?

Comment: Kerem, I feel you have some doubt about frequency, period, units, etc. that is not yet replied. I wish to help, could you please specify what are the two concepts for which you are asking the difference?

Comment: Just use angular frequency, \$\omega\: rad\: s^{-1}\$, instead of Hz and all these problems disappear.

Answer (score 4):

> I have signal like that \$ sin(2t) \$ frequency of this signal is \$ f = \frac 1 \pi \$ but I am confused here because this \$ \pi \$ equal 3.14 or 180° if signal is \$ sin(2 \pi t) \$ then \$ f = 1 \$ and everything is clear.

Yes, whoever is setting the question is making the maths easy. One cycle per second or 1 Hz.

Answer (score 1):

The general form for a sinusoid \$x(t)\$ is

$$\sin(2{\pi}ft + \phi)$$

Where \$f\$ is the frequency of the sinusoid and \$\phi\$ is some constant phase, which many times is set to zero. This general expression makes the \$2\pi\$-periodicity of the signal clear.

Questions that ask you to find the frequency of a simple sinusoid can be solved by setting \$2{\pi}ft\$ equal to whatever is in the argument of the sinusoid you're dealing with. People get too comfortable with seeing the \$\pi\$ term, so when it's no longer there it may throw you off.

The solution for the frequency \$f\$ is definitely more intuitive in the case of

$$2{\pi}ft\ = 2{\pi}t \Rightarrow f = 1 \text{ Hz}$$

Than

$$2{\pi}ft\ = 2t \Rightarrow f = \frac{1}{\pi} \text{ Hz}$$

Both answers are just constant numbers and whether or not you see \$\pi\$ is irrelevant, it is "built in" in to whatever expression is in the argument.